# JSViews syntax for converting value to select a template dynamically

Tags: jsviews

In a jsviews based app, I have a data object that contains a type attribute (actually a server type).

I'd like to convert it and append a suffix to pass to a tmpl inclusion.

Let's say I have :

```
$.views.converters({
    "serverSideTypeToLocalType": function(serverSideType) {
        switch(serverSideType) {
            case "server-side-type1":
                return "type1";
            case "server-side-type2":
                return "type2";
            case "server-side-type3":
                return "type3";
            default:
                throw "Invalid type";
        }
    }
});
```

I also have templates :

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id"type1-edit">
template for editing type 1
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id"type1-view">
template for viewing type 1
</script><script type="text/x-jsrender" id"type2-edit">
template for editing type 2
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id"type2-view">
template for viewing type 2
</script><script type="text/x-jsrender" id"type3-edit">
template for editing type 3
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id"type3-view">
template for viewing type 3
</script>
```

My data object is :

```
var data = { MyObjects : [
{
    "ServerSideType": "server-side-type1",
    "IsEditing" : true
},{
    "ServerSideType": "server-side-type2",
    "IsEditing" : false
}] };
```

How to construct a main template that includes dynamically the correct template based on `ServerSideType` and `IsEditing` properties ?

I tried :

```
<div>
{^{for MyObjects}}


        {^{include ^tmpl=({serverSideTypeToLocalType:ServerSideType}+ "-" + IsEditing ? "edit":"view")/}}

{{/for}}

</div>
```

but it fails with a weird error `Cannot read property 'bd' of undefined`.

Here is a reproductible sample:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $.views.converters({
      "serverSideTypeToLocalType": function(serverSideType) {
        switch (serverSideType) {
          case "server-side-type1":
            return "type1";
          case "server-side-type2":
            return "type2";
          case "server-side-type3":
            return "type3";
          default:
            throw "Invalid type";
        }
      }
    });


    var data = {
      MyObjects: [{
        "ServerSideType": "server-side-type1",
        "IsEditing": true
      }, {
        "ServerSideType": "server-side-type2",
        "IsEditing": false
      }]
    };


    var tmpl = $.templates("#main");
    tmpl.link("#container", data);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="main">
  <div>
    {^{for MyObjects}} 
    <p>Object n° {^{:#index +1}}</p>
    
   {^{include ^tmpl=({serverSideTypeToLocalType:ServerSideType}+ "-" + IsEditing ? "edit":"view")/}}       

    {{/for}}

  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type1-edit">
  <div>
    template for editing type 1
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type1-view">
  <div>
    template for viewing type 1
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type2-edit">
  <div>
    template for editing type 2
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type2-view">
  <div>
    template for viewing type 2
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type3-edit">
  <div>
    template for editing type 3
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type3-view">
  <div>
    template for viewing type 3
  </div>
</script>

<div id="container">Loading ...</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a (stripped down) example on a jsfiddle, so I can then try to propose a fix, and also look at the error message? Did you use unminified js files, to make error message diagnositics easier?

Comment: Hi @BorisMoore. I added a reproductible snippet. FYI, if I remove the `{^{include}}`, the snippet works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest a `{:...}` tag within the markup of a `{{...}}` tag.

I would suggest using a helper, rather than a converter:

```
{^{include ^tmpl="#" + ~serverToLocal(ServerSideType) + "-" + (IsEditing ? "edit":"view")/}}
```

You can also use a data-linked element:

```
<span data-link='{include ^tmpl="#" + ~serverToLocal(ServerSideType)+ "-" + (IsEditing ? "edit" : "view")}'></span>
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    function serverToLocal(serverSideType) {
      switch (serverSideType) {
        case "server-side-type1":
          return "type1";
        case "server-side-type2":
          return "type2";
        case "server-side-type3":
          return "type3";
        default:
          throw "Invalid type";
      }
    }

    var data = {
      MyObjects: [{
        "ServerSideType": "server-side-type1",
        "IsEditing": true
      }, {
        "ServerSideType": "server-side-type2",
        "IsEditing": false
      }]
    };

    var tmpl = $.templates("#main");
    tmpl.link("#container", data, {serverToLocal: serverToLocal});
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="main">
  <div>
{^{for MyObjects}} 
  <p>Object n° {^{:#index +1}}</p>
  <input data-link="ServerSideType" />
  <input data-link="IsEditing" type="checkbox"/>
  {^{include ^tmpl="#" + ~serverToLocal(ServerSideType) + "-" + (IsEditing ? "edit":"view")/}}
{{/for}}
  </div>

  Two:
  <div>
{^{for MyObjects}} 
  <p>Object n° {^{:#index +1}}</p>
  <span data-link='{include ^tmpl="#" + ~serverToLocal(ServerSideType)+ "-" + (IsEditing ? "edit" : "view")}'></span>
{{/for}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type1-edit">
  <div>
template for editing type 1
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type1-view">
  <div>
template for viewing type 1
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type2-edit">
  <div>
template for editing type 2
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type2-view">
  <div>
template for viewing type 2
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type3-edit">
  <div>
template for editing type 3
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="type3-view">
  <div>
template for viewing type 3
  </div>
</script>

<div id="container">Loading ...</div>
```

Comment: thanks! it works like a charm. Just for my curiosity: could a converter be used in this case ? (even if a bit more complicated) ?

Comment: Not really. It can be used for the initial rendering - along the lines of `<span data-link='{include tmpl={{:serverToLocal:ServerSideType}} ...}'></span>`, but that won't switch templates in response to observable changes of ServerSideType. You could create a custom tag that has the template string as argument, and uses a converter on that string, but I don't think it is worth the complexity.